# Access variable from parent in child angular2

Tags: angular

I have one variable in my parent component and I wanna edited in my child component.
I try out `@Input` but it seems didn't work! how can I achieve pass var to the child and also listen to the change?

Parent:

```ts
export class Parent implements OnInit {
    showModal : boolean = false;
}
```

Child:

```ts
export class Child implements OnInit {
    @Input() showModal: boolean;

    // calling this function on (click) button.
    closeModal() {
      this.showModal = false;
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```ts
export class Child implements OnInit {
    @Input() showModal: boolean;
    @Output() showModalChange:EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

    // calling this function on (click) button.
    closeModal() {
      this.showModal = false;
      this.showModalChange.emit(this.showModal);
    }
}
```

**parent element html**

```ts
<child [(showModal)]="showModal"
```

should do what you want.

Comment: it work, almost! but parent component doesn't reflect the changes. and still have older value.How can I tell parent to listen to changes?

Comment: I updated it for 2-way binding. For `[(...)]="..."` to work, the name of the input and output must match where the output has an additional `Change` suffix.

Comment: what is `showModalChange:EventEmitter` ? and why require this?

Comment: The input allows to pass a value for `showModal` to `Child` (`<child [showModal]="isModalVisible">`), `showModalChange` allows to notifiy the parent abut value changes when `closeModal()` was called (`<child (showModalChange)="isModalVisible = $event">`) or together ``<child [(showModal)]="isModalVisible">` (which only works if above naming convention is maintained)